# Redo the api call everytime I change the data value on VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to update a request of an axios.get
I have a method that adds 1 to the param data (the default value is 1), but even thought I'm updating the param value, the page won't change the content because it's not updating the get requisition
I know there something similar in react with componentDidUpdate method

Here's my code

Api request

```
  async created() {
    const {
      data: {
        data: { items, pagination },
      },
    } = await this.$axios.get(`/faq?page=${this.param}`)
  },
```

Method:

```
  methods: {
    next() {
      this.param = this.param + 1
    },
  },
```

So is it possible to redo the create() everytime i use the method next?

Answer (score 1):

`created()` hook is called only once during a lifecycle, you can use `watcher` instead in order to listen to variable changes

```
watch: {
  param: {
    immediate: true,
    handler(newVal, oldVal) {
      if (newVal !== oldVal) {
        await this.$axios.get(`/faq?page=${newVal}`)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For more info, please take a look at: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property